# Image set programmatically on navigation bar shown along with segue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, segue

I have set an image on my navigation bar programmatically like so...

```
let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 315, y: 12, width: 20,height: 20))
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

let img = "homeIcon"
let image = UIImage(named: img)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x:1, y: -1, width:20, height: 20)
myView.addSubview(imageView)


self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(myView)
```

Here what I am doing is I make a view, add an image to the view and then add the view to the navigation bar. But the issue is when I click on the row and navigate to another screen from this screen using a segue, the navigation bar of the next screen also shows the icon I have set on the previous screen. But I don't want this to happen. The next screen should not show the icon on the navigation bar. So what should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your presented view controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  for view in (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)! {
    if view.tag == 1 {
      view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
  }
}
```

And add your code for setting the image of the nav bar in your initial controller in `viewWillAppear` too, making sure to set the tag of the view containing the image view to be 1.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Setting the tag to the imageview as you suggested didn't work. But setting the tag to the view did made it work. Thanks..

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.. have edited the answer now.